# Jest Unit Testing function that calls a second one that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

**Edited Question with vazsonyidl suggestions applied**

I have to write unit tests for a function similar to this one:

```
import {External} from 'ExternalModule';

async functionA(){
    this.functionB().then((data) => {
        External.functionC(options);
        console.log("Reached1");

    }).catch((data) => {
        const { OnError = "" } = data || {}
        if(OnError) {
            External.functionC(anotherOptions);
            console.log("Reached2");
        }
    })
}

functionB() {
    return new Promise(() => {
    });
  }
```

As functionC belongs to another module, I placed a mock of it in the `_mocks_`folder:

```
//_mocks_/ExternalModule.ts

export var External: ExternalClass = {
  functionC(){}
}

class ExternalClass{
  constructor(){};
  functionC(){};
}
```

I have mocked functionB in two diferent ways for testing the `then` and the `catch` :

```
it("should test then block", () => {
        functionB = jest.fn(() => {return Promise.resolve()});

        const functionSpy = jest.spyOn(ExternalModule.External, 'functionC');
        void functionA().then(() => {
          expect(functionSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    })

it("should test catch block", () => {
        const err = { OnError: "Error" };
        functionB = jest.fn(() => {return Promise.reject(err)});

        const functionSpy = jest.spyOn(ExternalModule.External, 'functionC');
        void functionA().then(() => {
          expect(functionSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    })
```

What I am trying to do is expect that functionC was called and called with the correct params, but the test is always passing even if I test if functionC was not called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jest does not wait for the async code to complete before doing assertions.**

You can use the following function:

```
const waitForPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
```

to force Jest to wait for promises to complete before continuing like so:

```
it("does something", async () => {
  promiseCall();
  await waitForPromises();
  expect(something).toBe(something)
});
```

Comment: Although I'm getting the same problem in a similar function, but only when running all the test cases of the file. If I run only this one it passes. Any idea?

Comment: @RicardoCardoso I believe it might have something to do with mocks. Do you have any?
You can implement an `afterEach(() => {jest.restoreAllMocks();});` in the first describe. So if mocks are the culprit, they get reset after each test.

Answer (score 0):

I think when this function catch error, this error should have an 'OnError' property so the functionC can run.

```
const { OnError = "" } = data || {}
if(OnError) {
    ExternalClass.functionC(anotherOptions);
}
```

change you response error data to `return Promise.reject({OnError: '404'})` may solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. When rejecting the promise, the object err contains an OnError property. When debugging, funcionC is reached, but jest keeps telling me that it does not. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not providing it to your class.
The following code is working for me:

```js
class A {
  async functionA() {
    this.functionB().then((data) => {
      this.functionC(); // It woll log aaa here, you need this one.
    }).catch((data) => {
      const {OnError = ''} = data || {};
      if (OnError) {
        console.log('onerror');
      }
    });
  }

  functionB() {
    return new Promise(() => {
    });
  }

  functionC() {
    return 2;
  }
}

describe('a', () => {
  it('test',  () => {
    const a = new A();
    a.functionB = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());
    const functionBSpy = jest.spyOn(a, 'functionC');
    void a.functionA().then(() => {
      expect(functionBSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps, any comment appreciated.

*As you provided no information about your functionB I mocked something that may suitable for you*.

**Your original problem is that Jest does not wait for your callbacks to settle. It does the assertion although, even if your function calls happen later, Jest will not recognise them and says that no call ever occurred.**

There are several docs available, for example Jest's one [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)

Comment: I did not paste the functionB here for simplicity, but it exists and returns a Promise just like you did there. When debugging, functionC is reached, but jest keeps telling me that it does not. I will update the question with more details.

Comment: Because you are not setting up spies on your function call. I will be back with the answer within a minute.

Comment: Ok I understand your problem fully. So your functionA is not a synchoronus call. You need to handle this accordingly. If it is async - as I think should be - now you can handle your assertions in a then callback. Update the answer with the full working code.

Comment: So you think that I must change functionA to be async and then test it with something like: return functionA().then(() => { expect(functionC).tohaveBeenCalled() }) ?

Comment: I think it should happen that way, since your code does not look synchronous at a first glance. And Jest will not handle it synchoronus either. :)

Comment: Made the changes you suggested and now the test is always passing even if I check if functionC was called 5 times. As functionC is from an external module, I have a mock of the external class in _mocks_ folder with only the method signature, do you think that is has something to do with it?

Comment: I do think that worth another question.. Maybe there is something wrong with that, not related to this original question. :) If you want to test that the function had been called, you can and should use toHaveBeenCalled() instead counting on how many times.

Comment: Updated question with you suggestions applied and the mock implementation. Thanks for all you help.